# How to measure euclidean distance between points with vtkDelaunay3D package?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm working with python vtkDelaunay3D (scipy.spatial.Delaunay) package for a special purpose. Normally the package is used for triangulation/tetrahedralisation.

How do I measure euclidean distance between points with this package?

Comment: Hi, could you provide some more details so that we can all better understand which sort of data you are working with?

Comment: I gave up using vtk package.Instead, I have decided to use scipy.spatial.delaunay which is a more robust package

Comment: @Sara If you can provide a small working example, maybe you could add your scipy-based solution as an answer.

Comment: @bli thanks but I got the answer and did that project one month ago

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025784/how-to-visualize-3d-delaunay-triangulation-in-python